# Possible Scam - reply address appears to be yours

Tags: email-spoofing

Have received the following email which I believe to be a scam

*Internet Crime Complaint Center (IC3)
In Partnership with:
Swiss National Fraud Relief Center (NFRC)
Case/Reference ID: IE3033900045
We regret to inform you that you have been a victim of identity theft. Your identity and consumer credit file have been compromised and used in an identity theft scheme recently uncovered in Ireland by federal authorities.
Your more personal details have been undisclosed in this email for your own security as your email might have been compromised as well. The offenders have since been prosecuted, tried and ordered to pay restitution to victims involved willingly through wire fraud and romance or other scams, or unwillingly through identity theft and hacking. This means victims that had direct contact with the offenders by telephone or email in response to some type of scam and those who are hacked and are unaware of the incident prior to this notification. You have received this notification because this applies to you directly regardless of if you have lived in Ireland or not, that's where the case was opened and that's where the hackers were charged.
For more detailed information about this case and the settlement pay outs that you are entitled to, immediately contact the Office of International Affairs at the Limerick City District Court by replying to this notification, or by visiting in person at 38 Roxboro Road, Limerick, Ireland between 9:00 a.m. and 4:00 p.m., Monday through Friday, excluding Court holidays.
If you are visiting in person, set up an appointment prior to your visit by telephone: +353 800 814 250 (toll-free) or by email. If you are unable to make a trip, you will be rendered proper assistance online and on the telephone.
Regards,
Ilia Price
Administrative Clerk*

The send address was    Ilia Price 
The reply address was international.affairs@limerick-city.org

Are you able to confirm that is is a scam

Kind Regards
Richard Stafford

Comment: Unfortunately, we are not a scam site.

Comment: Your first clue: why is the ***Swiss*** National Fraud Relief Center operating out of ***Ireland***?

Comment: For the same reason that IC3 (a division of the FBI) does involve itself in cybercrimes globally. Of course, AFAIK there is no such organization as the "Swiss National Fraud Relief Center" but I am by no means certain it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Scam.

1. Like many such messages, it seems to be a very similar to several other variants of this type of message as seen by searching pieces of information in the email.
2. The messages I have found that match this almost to the word have at least three different "Administrative Clerks" signing off on them.
3. 38 Roxboro Road, Limerick, Ireland (to the best that I can find out) is the back side of Limerick Prison. The nearest court does share a street with Limerick Prison, but it isn't Roxboro.
4. +353 800 814 250 doesn't appear to be a valid toll free number for Ireland where the closest match for toll free numbers is 1800, so I assume a North American author found an Irish reference and falsely assumed that the 1 could be dropped.

I could keep digging, but if I had received this I would be fully comfortable calling this a scam and moving on.